# Retrieve information from session array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created session array and I have placed values there like the code below

```
$ar= array(
            'product_id' => $this->input->post('productid'),
            'qty'=> 1,

            );
            //creating products session array for the first time
            $this->session->set_userdata('products',$ar);
```

Now, How to retrieve those information? and I need to push new information to existing session array. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply fetch it and access it as an array:

```
$products = $this->session->userdata('products');

$id = $products['product_id'];
$qty = $products['qty'];
```

Pushing is similar:

```
$products['new_info'] = 'something'; // provided you already fetched the array
$this->session->set_userdata('products', $products);
// now the 'products' session variable contains 'product_id', 'qty' and 'new_info'
```